# Xamarin form android 14.0(API 34) not visible in target android version

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

Xamarin form android 14.0(API 34) not visible in target android version. I have downloaded android sdk platform 34 from Android SDK manager. but it still not visible in project property.

[image]

only can see till API-33
[image]
Please let me know if anyone knows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2612 (5.0.0 Service Release 15) Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0-sr15#may-10-2023---xamarinforms-5002599-pre1-500-service-release-15-pre-release-1). It now targets on Android 13.0 and has not published the Android 14 support.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17861 - in this link, they are talking about api 34 .. I hope their is support for api 34 if im not wrong.

Comment: As they are talking about maui project. Even i have created default maui project to test. Their also i dont find api34. Please help.

Comment: You can check this thread about [User Story: As a developer I can build applications with Android API 34](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14026). The team said that it would be supported in the .net8 preview 6.

Comment: You can wait for the .net 8 and update the .net version.